# A few tasks from group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can you tell me, if my solutions are good?

1. Mapping $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ with $f(k)=g^k$  is group homomorphism and Image(f) is abelian subgroup of G with $|\langle g \rangle |=ord(g)$

$f(k+l)=g^{k+l}=g^kg^l=f(k)f(l)$

$Im (f)=\{g^k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\} \iff \langle g \rangle=\{...,g^{-1},e,g^1,...\}$

For every $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}, \ f(k)*f(l)=g^kg^l=g^{k+l}\iff g^{k+l} \in \langle g \rangle$

$f(k+l)=f(l+k)$, so Im(f) is abelian.

2. $G$ is finite group, so every element $g\in G$ has finite order and $ord(g)| \ |G|$.

Let say that $a<b, a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. And I consider the set of powers $\{g^a \mid a \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subset of G and is infinite. So it have to be a repetition b with $g^a=g^b \rightarrow g^{a-b}=e$ , so every g has finite order.
Let |G|=n, ord(g)=m. Since $\langle g\rangle$ is subgroup of G, from Lagrange theorem $m \mid n$.

3. Show that $(\mathbb{C^*},*)$ (group with multiplication) has only one group with order m,namely $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid z^m=1\}=\langle \zeta \rangle$, where $\zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{m}}$

$\zeta^k=e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{m}}$ are distinct complex numbers, so it generates cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{C^*}$, but how to show that is only one?

Comment: You should consider using \langle and \rangle instead of > and < for subgroups.  It formats much better.

Comment: You might also consider using \mid instead of | for "such that" and "divides."  The spacing is better.

Comment: 3.) There is only one, because all cyclic subgroups of order $m$ are isomorphic. Every finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic.

Comment: Ok, "all cyclic subgroups of order m are isomorphic"
, but how is it equal to "is only one subgroup of order m" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x\in \mathbb{C}^*$ of order $m$, also, take $\zeta:=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{m}}$. Now if we set $P_m(X)=X^m-1$ we know (from basic polynomial theory) that $P_m$ will have at most $m$ distinct roots (it is essentially an application of the Euclidean division for the ring of polynomials over a field), fortunately all elements in $\langle \zeta\rangle$ are roots of $P_m$ and there are $m$ elements in $\langle \zeta\rangle$ because $\zeta$ is of order $m$.So $\langle \zeta\rangle$ cannot but be the set of all roots of $P_m$.

Now, by definition $x^m=1$ hence $P_m(x)=0$ hence $x$ is a root of $P_m$. Hence we have $\langle x\rangle\subseteq\langle \zeta\rangle$. By cardinality both sets are equal and hence you have only one cyclic subgroup of order $m$.